# How do I create a powerbi report to show the same results as a sql group by query

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have a sql server table. I have included a few of the columns from that table below

| status_id | region | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | South State | Sun City |
| 2 | South State | Sun City |
| 3 | North State | Rain City |
| 4 | North State | Sun City |

There are lots of statuses for each city. However there should only be one region for each city. In the example above there are 3 statuses for Sun City, but they are in 2 different regions.

In sql I can easily find which cities have this conflict with this query:

```
select count(distinct region), location
from status
group by location
having count(distinct region) > 1
```

This will return:

| count | location |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Sun City |

My question is how do I reproduce this query in powerbi? Note that I cannot make any changes to the sql server data. I just need to report on the conflicting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without writing any DAX by putting the `location` column into a matrix visual and adding `region` as the values field and setting the aggregation to Count (Distinct) using the dropdown and then using the filters to pick when these are greater than one.

[image: Matrix Visual]

Of course, you can write a calculated table with DAX too.

```
MultiRegions =
FILTER (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'status'[location],
        "count", CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'status'[region] ) )
    ),
    [count] > 1
)
```

[image: Calculated Table]